# Rails: Return highest and lowest associated records from a grouped association value taking the total number of associated records into account

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In our Rails application we have two tables:

```
products:
 - id
 - name

feedbacks
 - id
 - product_id
 - rating
```

So Products can have many feedbacks which have a rating (1-5).

What we want to do get the BEST and WORST Product by counting the number of feedbacks per product using (4-5) for BEST and (1-2) for WORST.

However we also need to take into account the total number of feedbacks for the product, otherwise if a product happened to have more feedback than another, it could end up being both the best and worst...

As an example, we've tried the following that 'should' return a list of products where the feedback rating is 4+ and then the first element would be the highest.

```
Product.joins(:feedbacks).group('feedbacks.rating').having('Max(rating) >= 4')
```

First question... is this the correct way to return this? Is there a better way to return only one record rather than returning an ActiveRecord relation and pulling the first record?

Second question... how do we take into account the number of feedbacks against the product? So the query becomes... 'Rating 4+ against total number of feedbacks on the product'

Comment: In big databases, wouldn't you have a background job that runs to update a field on Product records to calculate? Maybe `total_reviews` and `average_review_score`?

Answer (score 1):

Writing an SQL query that will calculating a quality ranking sounds intimidating.

This sounds like it could be an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), I'd approach it a different way:

##### Goal:

A `Product` needs to have a `ranking` compared to its siblings.

I think [the mathematicians can better speak to](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/942738/algorithm-to-calculate-rating-based-on-multiple-reviews-using-both-review-score) the algorithm you choose to set that `rank`.

My process for calculating `rank` would be something like this:

1. Add a `ranking` column to `Product`
2. Write a job that performs the "ranking" calculation
3. Trigger this job to run in the background either on a schedule, or when a `Feedback` is created / updated.
4. Use that `ranking` column for a very simple `.order_by(ranking: :desc)`